# Spread Syntax with Map and Filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, spread-syntax

I found this interesting problem and wanted to share with you guys.
The question is :

```
[...[0,1,...[-1,0,1].map((x)=> x+1)].filter((x)=>x)),7]
```

I easily solved the first section upto the filter as `[0,1,(-1+1),(0+1),(1+1)] = [0,1,0,1,2]`.

I was surprised to find the 7 hanging at the end. I thought it was some typo but copying the problem into the  console gave me [1,1,2,7]. I couldn't quite understand 2 things.

- why were the 0's left out of filter
- what's the 7 doing there

Comment: 0 is Javascript falsy, so the filter `(x)=>x` will remove it

Comment: What is the question? I don't see how code could be a question...

Comment: You seem to be asking "Why does `7` return `7`?" If this is not the question you mean to ask, perhaps you could rephrase it...

Comment: `.filter` keeps only those elements for which `x` is "thruthy". `0` is not. `(x) => x` is shorthand for `function(x) { return x }`

Comment: aww crap the 7 is part of array, I thought it was some weird stuffs added at the tail

Comment: This is the weirdest question I've seen in a while

Comment: **[`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)**

Answer (score 3):

- The first operation here is [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/map) `[-1, 0, 1].map(x => x + 1)` which basically adds `1` to each element, returning `[0, 1, 2]` array.
- Next one is [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter) operation, `[0, 1, ...[0, 1, 2]].filter(x => x)` which actually returns a new array, without every `falsy` value `(false, 0, undefined, null, "")` out of the array.
- The last operation looks like `[...[1, 1, 2], 7]` and gets rid of the nested array with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Spread_operator) returning `[1, 1, 2, 7]`.

Answer (score 1):

[...[0,1,...[-1,0,1].map((x)=> x+1)].filter((x)=>x),7] broken down:

```
[-1,0,1].map((x)=> x+1) // [0,1,2]

[0,1,...[-1,0,1].map((x)=> x+1)] // [0,1,0,1,2]

[0,1,...[-1,0,1].map((x)=> x+1)].filter((x)=>x) // [1,1,2]

[...[0,1,...[-1,0,1].map((x)=> x+1)].filter((x)=>x),7] // [1,1,2,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

this part `[-1,0,1].map((x)=> x+1)` results in this list `[0,1,2]` then this part `[0,1,...[-1,0,1].map((x)=> x+1)]` results in `[0,1,1,2]` which after the filter part drops the `0` so it results into `[1,1,2]`, finally the last element of the list is `7`. So, altogether the result is `[1,1,2,7]`

Answer (score 0):

The code evaluates in the following steps:

```
[...[0, 1, ...[-1, 0, 1].map((x)=>x+1)].filter((x)=>x)), 7] // map
[...[0, 1, ...[(x=>x+1)(-1), (x=>x+1)(0), (x=>x+1)(1)]].filter((x)=>x)), 7] // function application
[...[0, 1, ...[0, 1, 2]].filter((x)=>x)), 7] // spread
[...[0, 1, 0, 1, 2].filter((x)=>x)), 7] // filter
[...[...(x=>x)(0)?[0]:[], ...(x=>x)(1)?[1]:[], ...(x=>x)(0)?[0]:[], ...(x=>x)(1)?[1]:[], ...(x=>x)(2)?[2]:[]], 7] // function application
[...[...0?[0]:[], ...1?[1]:[], ...0?[0]:[], ...1?[1]:[], ...2?[2]:[]], 7] // conditional
[...[...[], ...[1], ...[], ...[1], ...[2]], 7] // spread (from filter)
[...[1, 1, 2], 7] // spread
[1, 1, 2, 7]
```